# Angular-Material2 md-button and date-picker z-index values

Tags: datepicker, z-index, angular-material2

I'm trying out this [Angular-material2-datepicker](https://github.com/koleary94/Angular-2-Datepicker). It seems the z-index is not working correctly. In the source code, I can see the z-index is set to 10000, but not sure why it shows up behind my material md-button, which I'm not sure what's the z-index value.

How Can I bring up the date picker?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to decrease the buttons z-index.

Comment: I tried. I also used md-card, the button would be behind the md-card if I decrease the z-index of the button. Maybe I should decrease everything and leave the datepicker?